# Cannot Paste HTML into String in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, indentation, pasting

I am trying to parse some HTML by passing in the HTML into a single string object. However, when I paste in the HTML, I get a ton of underlines in pyCharm, which I suspect is because of the formatting (See screenshot). This breaks my program, because I am splitting on \n\n, which should represent a blank line.

This is what I get when I paste in the code:

[image: badPyCharm]

However, this is what I want, which has no problems when I split the string with \n\n:

[image: goodPyCharm]

I have tried pasting the html that I want to use as a string into notePad and converting to plainText, but to no avail. I have also turned off any 'auto indent' features in PyCharm. Can anyone tell me how to fix this, so I can paste in longer chunks of HTML (of the same structure, separated by blank lines) and still have my code work? Or is there some way to now what to split the string by when I paste in long chunks of HTML (my intuition is that some tabs get added, but I can't figure it out)?!

Comment: Code highlighting has no effect on program execution, really. You can paste your minimal code and a HTML string example here to make sure things work.

Comment: I know, but I think it is highlighting it because of tabbed indentation, which means my code on line 31 doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd go with a simple editor like Notepad++ or VSCode on Windows and see what exactly are whitespace symbols. However you have a very good answer below for PyCharm magics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say as a way of help without having access to the real HTML/XML text (not as an image) and seeing that both sample texts look different if compared to each other

1. Your code shouldn't break because of something wrong inside your text variable when you use triple single/double quotes --off-topic comment from [PEP-0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings) is that you use triple *double* quotes for docstring instead of multi-line text (on which you use triple *single* quote)
2. You can always try any HTML/XML formatter online and paste your text in there before adding it in your IDE script. Alike you do with JSON-formatted content to check the validity. Those formatters help detect what is wrong in your text according to the parsing criterion
3. Another option, since you're using BeautifulSoup, pass your "fullHtmlString" variable as parameter with the "lxml" parser (you have to install it at OS level [`libxml2` and `libxslt`] and via pip [`pip3.6 install lxml` as an example] before) and let BeautifulSoup help you see what is *visibly* wrong in your HTML/XML text while printing it

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fullHtmlString, 'lxml')
   print(soup.prettify())
   ```
4. You can use "reformat code" and "fill paragraph" options together in PyCharm to format your entire code, especially when is outside margins according to [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) that, when combined, you usually see by yourself whatever errors you have in a syntax sense

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Thanks! Pasting it into an html formatter first did the trick! I also had to declare the encoding, thanks for your help :)